# How to split a table by column for printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have an html table on my page on which I am also using the [datatables jquery plugin](https://datatables.net/). My table has 30 columns and I am using the [jQuery.print plugin](https://github.com/DoersGuild/jQuery.print) to print the table.

It looks like this in landscape mode:
[image]

It looks cramped so how can I split this table at a certain column to print it on two landscape pages?

Comment: And you have tried what?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I don't even know how to go about it.

Comment: So how do you expect others to help you? Also *"split this table" Where? You need to be more specific if you want people to help. Have you thought about opening the table in a new window after splitting it for the print layout?

Comment: If I don't even know where to start, how can I provide code? I am not even asking for sample code, just an idea on how others would go about tackling such an issue. I did mention i want to split the table at a certain column. No, I hadn't thought about that.

Comment: I haven't asked for any source code. I'm just curious to what you have tried and which certain column are you wanting to split the table from. This is what I mean by be more specific. If you don't tell us then we don't know...

Comment: Change the table so the cols are listed down the page instead.

Comment: @NewToJS Fair enough.

Comment: @Andy I am not sure I follow, Andy. I can't change the table layout at all unfortunately.

Comment: Why not? You're in charge of how the data is displayed and it would solve your problem. If your data is 30 rows down and 4 across (a pivot of your table) you won't have to split the table.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now! So can I do this using css like this `-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);` and then after print return it to normal?

Comment: I don't know if that will work, but if it does, that would be a neat solution.

Comment: I managed to get the cols to display listed down on a portrait page using your idea. I am going to give the column I want it to break at a class and see if I can get it to work that way. Thanks Andy

Answer (score 0):

Put a media query in your css for print, then do a table > tr > td {display:block} and go from there. Block may be the wrong style, but you get the jist.

Comment: Thanks @BlueDan, i'll give that a try (I still haven't found out a solution for my problem)